# How does Postgres choos which index to use in case if multiple indexes are present?

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, database-indexes

I am new to Postgres and a bit confused on how Postgres decides which index to use if I have more than one btree indexes defined as below.

```
CREATE INDEX index_1 ON sample_table USING btree (col1, col2, COALESCE(col3, 'col3'::text));

CREATE INDEX index_2 ON sample_table USING btree (col1, COALESCE(col3, 'col3'::text));
```

I am using col1, col2, COALESCE(col3, 'col3'::text) in my join condition when I write to sample_table (from source tables) but when I do a explain analyze to get the query plan I see sometimes that it uses index_2 to scan rather than index_1 and sometimes just goes with sequential scan .I want to understand what can make Postgres to use one index over another?

Comment: In a nutshell: the optimizer evaluates different strategies and assigns a cost value to each. Then takes the one with the lowest cost. See the [Using EXPLAIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html) for some more explanation on that

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name,for your explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output, I can only give a generic answer.

PostgreSQL considers all execution plans that are feasible and estimates the row count and cost for each node. Then it takes the plan with the lowest cost estimate.

It could be that the condition on `col2` is sometimes more selective and sometimes less, for example because you sometimes compare it to rare and sometimes to frequent values. If the condition involving `col2` is not selective, it does not matzer much which of the two indexes is used. In that case PostgreSQL prefers the smaller two-column index.

Comment: Great Thanks @Laurenz Albe for explaning, One more question on the same lines , Can postgres sql be forced/hinted to use an index and if it is possible, is it a good idea to do that ?

Comment: No, that is not possible. As long as the query is executed efficiently, the index used shouldn't matter. Consider dropping one of the indexes for more plan stability, shorter planning time and more efficient data modifications.